# How do I target a specific character for styling with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a series of double and triple word combinations that require the use of a hyphen to function in a filter situation, but I don't want to hyphens to show on the web page. Therefore I would like to target them using jQuery and change their color to blend in with the background of the page.

I have words like Social-Media, Content-Management, etc., and they show up in a context like this:

```
<li><a class="filterName" href="#Content-Management">Content-Management</a></li>
```

I have been able to target the entire word with effect, but I have not been able to just target the hyphen.

I have tried the following:

```
$('a.filterName:("\-\")').css("color", "red");
```

What is the correct way to target the hyphen?

Comment: The best way to fix that would be to not put the hyphen in on the backend that generates the page, not to make it "invisible" using jQuery.

Comment: You need to wrap it in a SPAN and apply a class/style to the SPAN.

Comment: The hyphen is essential for the filtering and the values are brought in dynamically, hence the option for a span is nil.

Comment: You can replace them with spaces?

Comment: Mr Potter, the hyphens are essential for the filtering. 5 points from Gryffindor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('a:contains("-")').html(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace('-', '<span class="hideme">-</span>')
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6Q7UA/)**

Comment: I would suggest changing the `opacity` to 0 rather than setting the `color` to blend with the `background-color` in case the `background-color` changes but otherwise, this works great.

Comment: @Jnatalzia - just doing what the OP asked for ("I would like to target them using jQuery and change their color to blend in with the background of the page")

Comment: j08691, thank you for the effective solution. Exactly what I needed, with a tip of the hat to Jnatalzia for recommending opacity 0.